# Make epoll return an fd once, without writing

Tags: python, file-descriptor, epoll

I have a master and a worker thread. The master thread accepts incoming connections and reads once from them. He then calls epoll.register(sock). The worker does epoll.poll() and does further reading and processing of incoming data.

The thing is: If there incoming data is very short, no more data coming from the fd after the first read which is done in the master thread, the worker thread is forever blocking in epoll.poll(). What he should do is, he should at least once wake up and return the newly added file descriptor.

How can I do this.

My current approach:

Master:

```
worker.epoll.register(sock.fileno())
worker.forced_fds_to_handle.add(sock.fileno())
```

Worker:

```
while True:
  for fileno, event in self.epoll.poll(1):
    self.forced_fds_to_handle.discard(fileno)
    self._process(fileno, event)

  while self.forced_fds_to_handle:
    fileno = self.forced_fds_to_handle.pop()
    self._process(fileno, select.EPOLLIN)
```

What I don't like about this approach: In the worst case the worker ignores the incoming fd for a second which means delay for my clients. Of course I could make the timeout smaller but then it would  somehow waste resources.

I'd really appreciate if somebody knew something better.

I already tried:

In the master:

```
sock.write('')
```

... to trigger an EPOLLIN, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The default value for `epoll.poll()` is -1 and as far as I remembern if you enter 0. it will not wait at all, just check whether there is some input or not.
That would solve your problem.

**However**, what I would be worry about is of a very CPU consuming loop with a `while True` and no waiting/blocking/sleeping that could diminish the pressure on the processor. If you find yourself in this situation, consider waiting/blocking/sleeping for 0.1 seconds and **none would even notice***!  ;-) I promise... :-)

Comment: Thanks for your response @Javier. It's true, 0.1 is hard to notice and would be an option. But: I still don't like it very much, it feels a bit dirty.

Comment: Hi @jcvj ! Just think about it: this doen't mean that you waste 0.1 seconds but that *there is nothing to process during this 0.1 seconds*! It is perfectly justified: **No-input/No-processing**. And the only one that waits/blocks is the worker that listens to **one** client, the other workers (if they exist) can keep listening to the clients which DO have something to send/process.